# Como armar una TABLA TEMPORAL para la sifuiente consulta en BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

He tratado de armar una tabla temporal con WITH, pero en recibo el alerta de error. no logro identificar el problea. Tambien he intentado lo mismo con CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE y SELEC INTO, pero aun asi no he podido dar con la falla.

```
WITH analysis_fall_2021_season AS
(SELECT
start_station_id,
end_station_id,
EXTRACT (DATE FROM started_at) AS start_date,
EXTRACT (DATE FROM ended_at) AS end_date, 
EXTRACT (TIME FROM started_at) AS start_time,
EXTRACT (TIME FROM ended_at) AS end_time,
DATETIME_DIFF (ended_at,started_at, MINUTE) AS total_lenght,
member_casual,
FROM 
(SELECT
fall_analysis.ride_id,
fall_analysis.start_station_id,
fall_analysis.end_station_id, 
fall_analysis.started_at, 
fall_analysis.ended_at, 
fall_analysis.start_station_name, 
fall_analysis.end_station_name, 
fall_analysis.member_casual,
FROM 
`ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202010` AS fall_analysis
INNER JOIN 
`ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202011` AS fall_202011
ON 
fall_analysis.member_casual = fall_202011.member_casual
INNER JOIN 
`ciclystic.cyclistic_seasonal_analysis.fall_202012` AS fall_202012
ON 
fall_analysis.member_casual = fall_202012.member_casual))
```

Comment: ¿No te sobra una coma tras el fall_analysis.member_casual y otra tras meber_casual? Sería mucho más fácil si en este tipo de preguntas añadieses el mensaje de error

Comment: Gracias! el mensaje de alerta es en la ultima linea: Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got end of script at [30:62].  Pero ya he probado tanto lo de las comas excedentes como borrar uno, otro y ambos parentesis. Sin embargo no resulta